# rMBP 15-inch, Mid 2015 Kernel Panics 10.12.4

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

New MacBook Pro 2015 Kernel Panics frequently. I have reset the PRAM yet the problem persists. Any ideas whats going on and how to fix?

Here is the Panic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       AF5640BB-45E1-48A3-D7BE-BC8E4839BF1B

Mon May 22 09:38:51 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 4): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 
0xffffff803a695c40, spinlock owner: 0xffffff803d4fdbe0, current_thread: 
0xffffff803d4fdbe0, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x4
RAX: 0xffffff803b10f478, RBX: 0xffffff801955d3b0, RCX: 
0xffffff803ea49710, RDX: 0xffffff803ea496c8
RSP: 0xffffff922be9bea0, RBP: 0xffffff922be9bf60, RSI: 
0xffffff801955d3b0, RDI: 0xffffff803a695c00
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff922be9bf84, R10: 
0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff81f7b5e058
R12: 0x0000000000000040, R13: 0xffffff803a695c00, R14: 
0xffffff803ea49660, R15: 0xffffff803ea496c8
RFL: 0x0000000000000282, RIP: 0xffffff801955d742, CS:  
0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f7c42f70 : 0xffffff80192005a1 
0xffffff81f7c42fd0 : 0xffffff801909d709 
0xffffff922be9bf60 : 0xffffff801955e0e1 
0xffffff922be9bfb0 : 0xffffff801909a8f7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: opendirectoryd

Mac OS version:
16E195

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-
3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06F94FD7-451F-34A1-B13C-D68FF7EDE0A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8019000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018f00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16227837603554
last loaded kext at 15499844644739: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 
(addr 0xffffff7f9d01f000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 15488484720633: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9d01f000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.kaspersky.kext.mark.1.0.6   1.0.6
com.kaspersky.kext.kimul.46 46
com.kaspersky.nke   2.3.0a7
com.kaspersky.kext.klif 3.4.3a31
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.14.41
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.4f18
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.14.41
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.59.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.1
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 114
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  114
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1150.9.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.50.19
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.41
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   514.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.5.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.41
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    311.11
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    514.10
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  308.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   199
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.14
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.16
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80195591f0): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff803a695c40, lock owner thread=0xffffff803d4fdbe0, current_thread: 0xffffff803bacc078, lock owner active on CPU 0x4, current owner: 0xffffff803d4fdbe0"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.51.2/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:427
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82036c3850 : 0xffffff80190ec3ec 
0xffffff82036c38d0 : 0xffffff80195591f0 
0xffffff82036c3910 : 0xffffff80195d4088 
0xffffff82036c3960 : 0xffffff80195d3d30 
0xffffff82036c3990 : 0xffffff801946db3d 
0xffffff82036c3c10 : 0xffffff801945ad67 
0xffffff82036c3c60 : 0xffffff801945c755 
0xffffff82036c3db0 : 0xffffff80193b3672 
0xffffff82036c3de0 : 0xffffff801938a169 
0xffffff82036c3e70 : 0xffffff801937f919 
0xffffff82036c3f20 : 0xffffff801937e069 
0xffffff82036c3fb0 : 0xffffff801909a8f7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0172.B16, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.124.1a2)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.4f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500,28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: Logitech USB Headset
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Have you tried running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)?  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: Is your MBP connected to any sort of file sharing or authentication servers at your place of employment or school/university? In addition, could your MBP be connected to a MDM system?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes it is connected to our Company DC.

Comment: I suggest you contact your IT department and have them do some troubleshooting for you. Sometimes all it takes is to unbind/rebind your computer from/to the DC server.

Answer (score 1):

I would back up your data and then completely erase and reinstall the latest version of macOS, to rule out the possibility of corrupted software or drivers that may be causing the panics.

See [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

Once that is all done I would try to start using the computer again. If you are unable to reinstall because of panics or the panics return after re-installing, its likely a hardware failure, and at this point there is not much you can do but take it to an [Apple Authorized Service provider](https://locate.apple.com/) for repairs or replacement.

Comment: This remedy is a little heavy handed as a first step, and probably could wait until it becomes a last resort. There may be a simple misconfiguration that can be fixed by getting some more detail back from @Marcelo Marques and trying to narrow the problem down.